# What is the maximum size of a vector?

Tags: c++

Why can't this code handle `n=100000000` (8 zeros)?

The code will be terminated by this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

So, the word "DONE" won't be printed out.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <long long> v1;
    long long n; cin>>n;
    for(long long i=0;i<n;i++){
        v1.push_back(i+1);
    }
    cout<<"DONE"<<endl;
}
```

Although the maximum size of `v1` is 536870911.

Comment: You run out of memory. This is what std::bad_alloc is telling you.

Comment: You are creating that vector on the stack. Why? - Thats to say, dont.

Comment: @Cortex that's not it, only a couple of pointers go on the stack this way, not the data itself

Comment: Hmm, guess I need to readup on my stuff then. - Apologies

Comment: @Cortex a `std::vector` dynamically allocates it's memory. Having it on the stack is *not* a problem.

Comment: A `std::vector` needs *contiguous* memory, because it's a random-access container. A linked list like `std::forward_list` *may* be able to hold more elements if your memory pool is fragmented, but each element in the linked list takes more data to hold the next pointer. If you're at a point in your career where you need to worry about something like that, though, you should also have some idea of how to solve it. In conclusion, I have no idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: A `std::vector`'s maximum theoretical size in "number of elements" is whatever size your implementation's `size_type` of the `std::vector` is. Usually `std::size_t`. But you still need enough memory to fit all those pounds of sausage.

Comment: Is this a 64 bit application?

Comment: `std::vector<long long> v1; std::cout << v1.max_size() << '\n';` will give you a number that's pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` contains a pointer to a single dynamically allocated *contiguous* array. As you call `push_back()` in your loop, that array has to grow over time whenever the vector's `size()` exceeds is `capacity()`. As the array grows large, it becomes more difficult for a new larger *contiguous* array to be allocated to copy the old array elements into. Eventually, the array is so large that a new copy simply can't be allocated anymore, and thus `std::bad_alloc` gets thrown.

To avoid all of those reallocations while looping, call the vector's `reserve()` method before entering the loop:

```cpp
int main() {
    vector <long long> v1;
    long long n; cin>>n;

    v1.reserve(n); // <-- ADD THIS!

    for(long long i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        v1.push_back(i+1);
    }

    cout<<"DONE"<<endl;
}
```

That way, the array is allocated only 1 time.

Answer (score 7):

> What is the maximum size of a vector?

Depends on several factors. Here are some upper limits:

- The size of the address space
- The maximum representable value of `std::vector::size_type`
- The theoretical upper limit given by `std::vector::max_size`
- Available memory - unless system overcommits and you don't access the entire vector
- Maximum available memory for a single process may be limited by the operating system.
- Available contiguous address space which can be less than all of the free memory due to fragmentation.

The address space isn't an issue in 64 bit world.

Note that the size of the element type affects the number of elements that fit in a given range of memory.

The most likely the strictest limit in your case was the available memory. 536870911 is one `long long` short of 4 gigabytes.

Comment: What does it mean, _"536870911 is one `long long` short of 4 gigabytes."_? (I'm not a native English speaker...)

Answer (score 3):

From cppref [max_size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size) docs:

> This value typically reflects the **theoretical limit** on the size of the container ...
>
> At runtime, **the size of the container may be limited to a value smaller than max_size() by the amount of RAM available**.